# Generate lib to link in c from 32 bit dll stdcall functions without decoration

Tags: c, windows, dll, lib, decoration

Generating `xxx.lib` from xxx.dll with both name and ordinal can be done with a `xxx.def` generated from `xxx.dll`'s `dumpbin` results (consider a dll with void foo() and void bar(int)):

```
dumpbin -exports xxx.dll

Exports

       ordinal    name
             0    foo
             1    bar
```

Then process this result, and generate the following `xxx.def`

```
EXPORTS

    foo    @0
    bar    @1
```

And then the following to generate the `xxx.lib`

```
lib /def:xxx.def
```

This works with c++ decorated names, but not so intuitive with C functions. C functions have decorations, and it seems lib tool accepts the names as C function names. So the export symbols in the above `xxx.lib` is in-fact `_foo` and `_bar` mapped to `foo` and `bar` in the dll.

This works with most 64 bit things, since calling convention is the same, all you need is to declare the function as a normal cdecl c function. In 32 bit, however, the compiler looks for _foo@0 and _bar@4 for stdcall (you cannot specify cdecl in import, since they are fundamentally different), and cannot be satisfied.

Is there a way to still statically load 32 bit dll when you have the header but not source code? (A loader should be possible, but that would mean much more work to do, and that's dynamic)

Comment: The .def file can specify both, write (say) `bar=_bar@4 @1`

Comment: @HansPassant it seems in 32 bit this just gives `_bar` symbol in `xxx.lib`. Notice the underscore before the name. Tested on vs2022 x86 native tools (x64 gives `bar` without underscore).

Comment: @HansPassant The dll I got have no underscore in export symbol, just plain `bar`, that's why I was exporting with ordinal (ignore name inside `xxx.dll`, works on x64). The problem is I do not have a `xxx.lib` that have no decoration, and lib tool in 32 bit adds the underscore decoration incorrectly.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realize that dumpbin of `xxx.lib` always have cdecl decorated name in lib. But now the problem changes to how to make the import code resolve to the corresponding symbol (without decoration), but looking at kernel32.lib, I think I will have to manually use the decorated names in `xxx.def`, and it seems that will resolve to the undercoated symbols in dll at runtime?